# Code runs without errors but does not change label text

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, nimbus, jradiobutton

I have been working with this for a while now, and I can't get the text for the two `JLabel`s to change on a click event.

Any help would be very welcome.  Thank you in advance.

This is a GUI program with two radio button button groups that pulls input from a field and makes a calculation.  It then sends the calculation to a `JLabel` and then makes a calculation based on that to send to a second `JLabel`.

Code:

---

```
public void jRB1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // Set the Length of Loan to 1 year:
    year = 1;
}

public void jRB2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // Set the Length of Loan to 2 years:
    year = 2;
}

public void jRB3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // Set the Length of Loan to 3 years:
    year = 3;
}

public void jRB4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // Set the Length of Loan to 4 years:
    year = 4;
}

public void jRB5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // Set the Length of Loan to 5 years:
    year = 5;
}

public void jRB6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // Set the Length of Loan to 6 years:
    year = 6;
}

public void jRB7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // Set the Intrest Rate to 5%:
    intrest = 5;
}

public void jRBActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // Set the Intrest Rate to 10%::
    intrest = 10;
}

public void jRB9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // Set the Intrest Rate to 12%:
    intrest = 12;
}

public void CalcActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // Button Click will get the value of the Loan from the jTFLoanAmmount
    // Performs the calculation RP = Loan Amount * (Interest Rate / 12) / [1-(1 + (Interest Rate / 12))^ - // (The length of Loan *12)]:
    //It will then send the result to the jLRPOut JLable
    //It will then send the result of the above calculation *(The length of Loan *12) to the //jLTotalLoanOut JLable
    double RP=(double)((Double.parseDouble(jTFLoanAmount.getText()))*(ir)/(1-1/Math.pow(1+ir, month)));
    jLRPOut.setText(String.valueOf(RP));
    double TLC=(double)((Float.parseFloat(jLRPOut.getText()))*(month));
    jLTotalLoanOut.setText(String.valueOf(TLC));
}


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /*
     * Set the Nimbus look and feel
     */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /*
     * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
     * default look and feel. For details see
     * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AOOADJavaLoanCalculator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AOOADJavaLoanCalculator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AOOADJavaLoanCalculator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AOOADJavaLoanCalculator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /*
     * Create and display the form
     */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new AOOADJavaLoanCalculator().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton Calc;
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jL1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jL2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jL3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLRPOut;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLTotalLoanOut;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRB;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRB1;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRB2;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRB3;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRB4;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRB5;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRB6;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRB7;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRB9;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTFLoanAmount;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;
// End of variables declaration                   

// My Variables
public int year = 0;
public int month = year * 12;
public int intrest = 0;
public double ir = intrest / 12;

}
```

Comment: You don't show us the code creating the two labels, the button, and adding the listener to the button. You also don't say what happens when you click the button. Have you tried debugging the code?

Comment: I have been at this for a while and have made a lot of changes that clean things up but it looks like NetBeans generated the code for the button and you guessed it there is no listener on the button.  Trying to figure out how to add it.

Comment: I would avoid NetBeans code generation completely. Or at least only use it to generate the GUI, but not to add listeners and logic.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  I am very new to Java and it's kind of like a crutch for me right now.  I figured out how to modify the generated code for the Calc button and now it generates output.  It's broken mathematically but hey it changes the text and for right now that's huge.  Thank you Thank you Thank you JB Nizet!

Comment: +1 for your first question, though visit these links before posting your next question :-) [Perfect Question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx), [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and [Smart Question](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: How do you bind events and actions ? ...something like `myButton.addAction/Event/OrAnythingElseListener(Listener)` ?

Comment: I got it to work btw so I wanted to share my result.

Comment: public void CalcActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

 int month = 0;
        double interest = 0;
        double loanAmt = ((Double.parseDouble(jTFLoanAmount.getText()))-(Double.parseDouble(jTFDownPayment.getText())));

if (jRB1.isSelected())
            month = 12;
else if (jRB2.isSelected())
            month = 24;

if (jRB7.isSelected())
            interest = 0.05;
        else if (jRB8.isSelected())
            interest = 0.1;

double ir = (interest / 12);

double RP = (double) ((loanAmt * ir) / (1 -1/Math.pow((1 + ir), month)));

Comment: jLRPOut.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(RP));
        double TLC = (double) (RP*month);
                //(((Double.parseDouble(jTFLoanAmount.getText()))* (interest/12)) /(1-1/Math.pow(1+(interest/12), month)));
        jLTotalLoanOut.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##") .format(TLC));
    }